# How to auto sum input fields with currency format

Tags: javascript, jquery, currency

I need to sum the input fields with currency format to the total input. I can make it work when it's only number. Here is my fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/nobuts/F2wEK/2/

The `onKeyUp` auto comma function is work correctly but It cannot sum those number anymore. 
Here is my JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".cost").each(
    function(){
    $(this).keyup(
        function(){
        calculateSum()
            });
        });
    });

    function calculateSum(){
        var sum=0;
        $(".cost").each(
        function(){
            if(!isNaN(this.value)&&this.value.length!=0){
                sum+=parseFloat(this.value);
                }
            });             
        $("#sum").val(sum.toFixed(2));
        }
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input.cost').keyup(function(event){
  // skip for arrow keys
  if(event.which >= 37 && event.which <= 40){
  event.preventDefault();
  }
  var $this = $(this);
  var num = $this.val().replace(/,/gi, "").split("").reverse().join("");

  var num2 = RemoveRougeChar(num.replace(/(.
3})/g,"$1,").split("").reverse().join(""));     
  console.log(num2);


  // the following line has been simplified. Revision history contains original.
  $this.val(num2);  
});});
function RemoveRougeChar(convertString){   

if(convertString.substring(0,1) == ","){

    return convertString.substring(1, convertString.length)            

}
return convertString;
}
```

Would be appreciated if you guys reply in fiddle.

Comment: It's working fine for me in Chrome, can you describe what is your problem and how to reproduce it in your fiddle?

Comment: Nelson, was the sum input correct as well?

Comment: Yes, I inputted `2.1` in each box and the result was `8.40`

Comment: Nelson, Please try to put the value over 1000 then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the comma in the number so `isNaN()` recognizes it as a number, so, replace your following code:

```
        if(!isNaN(this.value)&&this.value.length!=0){
            sum+=parseFloat(this.value);
        }
```

for this one:

```
            var vl = this.value.replace(',','');
            if(!isNaN(vl) && vl.length!=0){
                sum+=parseFloat(vl);
            }
```

See [**working fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/F2wEK/4/)

Comment: Nelson it works now but is it possible to make the sum in currency format as well?

Answer (score 1):

I just develop plugin to make it a lot easier, try this

http://www.xsanisty.com/calx/

and here is the sample with currency format

http://prototype.xsanisty.com/calx/sample/roi.html

http://prototype.xsanisty.com/calx/sample/calx_custom_language.html

Comment: ikshan, it works great but a bit late man :) Thank you anyway.